# Sonar-runner slow analysis execution of a .java file

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am running a Java code analysis sonar-runner connecting sonarqube v2.4 server 4.5.4. About 900 files ' .java ' are analyzed.

The problem comes when it is "hanging " analyzing a particular file. Every so often repeating the same trace :

> 13: 50: 07,522 INFO - 22/941 Analyzed files

I note that the heap memory is consumed slowly, until an error occurs. But I upgraded the memory to the process, and still remains in the same file analyzing. Has it occurred to anyone this behavior? For now I have no choice but to exclude the analysis of the affected class.

Comment: @Mattia - Please start using a more descriptive edit summary. "change in the forms" doesn't tell edit reviewers anything about what you were trying to achieve with the edit, and you've reused that phrase for many different edit suggestions. Everyone else can ignore this comment - I'm just providing some feedback to an editor.

Comment: @skrrgwasme thank you for your feedback. Anyway if an edit is not appropriated it will be reject from the community, and this is not the case!! Best regards.

Comment: @Mattia Unfortunately that is often not the case. If you go on [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and search for "robo reviewer" you'll see many posts about reviewers who are only interested in getting the review badge and don't really pay attention. Just because edits have been approved it doesn't necessarily mean they are good - they may get approved by people who don't care. I assure you that there is an expectation of good edit summaries.